# Generating custom legend (and only a legend) in matplotlib Python2

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a custom legend using matplotlib.  The [example in the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#plotting-guide-legend) doesn't work on my set up.  Neither does this follow.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

patch1 = mpatches.Patch(color='#a6cee3', label='Blue')
patch2 = mpatches.Patch(color='#1f78b4', label='Bluerish')
patch3 = mpatches.Patch(color='#33a02c', label='Greener')
patch4 = mpatches.Patch(color='#fdbf6f', label='Kind of orange')
patch5 = mpatches.Patch(color='#ff7f00', label='Orange')

all_handles = (patch1, patch2, patch3, patch4, patch5)

leg = ax.legend(all_handles)

ax.add_artist(leg)
plt.show()
```

How can I make it produce the desired legend?

I'm using Mac OSX 10.10.3, Python 2.7.6, Matplotlib 1.3.1.

Edit: @xnx's solution below works for Python 3, and works for Python 2.7.11 if using Matplotlib 2.1.1 (thanks @DavidG).

Comment: Have you tried with newer versions of matplotlib? The solution below works for me on Python 2.7, matplotlib 2.1.1 (although I am on windows....)

Comment: This works, I've accepted the answer below.  Good call @DavidG - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `handles` argument to `ax.legend` explicitly:

```
leg = ax.legend(handles=all_handles)
```

I think the issue with your code is that the first (positional) argument to `legend` is otherwise taken to be a sequence of objects you wish to label and you don't have any.

[image]

Comment: That gives me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_axes'`.

Comment: I don't get any error but this still doesn't work for me either without calling a `plt.draw` afterward. @P-robot, in which function is that error?

Comment: From `ax.legend()`, the bad call traces `ax.add_artist(leg)` which gives an error from `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/axes.pyc in add_artist(self, a)` in the following line (1454) `a.set_axes(self)`.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm using IPython 3.1.0.  If that makes a difference.  I just updated to IPython 4.0.0, and it still gives the same error.

Comment: I've updated python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, sympy, nose, but the problem persists with the same error.

Comment: I can reproduce this with the system Python on Mac OS X. I don't have a fix for you, but can tell you that it works under [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) which might be the way to go if you don't have a particular attachment to the system Python.

Comment: On the other hand, it does seem that this issue is related to the fact that you don't have any objects plotted on your axes, so you could try adding them (before adding the legend!)

Comment: This works in Python 2.7.11 with matplotlib version 2.1.1.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
This solved it for me:

```
leg = **plt**.legend(all_handles)
```